# I am trying to make an animation, I have my camera there and and Im trying to look thought the camera to see my objects but can't access it

Tags: camera

I have tried (0), (control+command+0), (command 0)but none of it works for me. Can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: When you say you tried (0) do you mean the 0 key on the keyboard, or the 0 key on the number pad.  You want to use the one on the number pad.  Also, if your keyboard has a Num Lock key, you want it on.  Finally, if those are all true, what happens when you press number pad 0?